# Name will not display

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf

I have my code compiling without issue, accepting input without issue, printing without issue. HOWEVER, it does not want to print the name it only prints a space. It was working and I made some additional changes and I don't know what went wrong. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct File {
char type;
char name;
int time;
int size;
}f;

int main()
{
struct File * c = malloc(1 *sizeof(struct File));
printf("Enter file name: \n");
scanf("%s", &f.name);
printf("Enter the file size: \n", f.size);
scanf(" %d", &f.size);
printf("Enter when the file was last accessed: \n", f.time);
scanf(" %d", &f.time);
printf("Enter the file type: \n", f.type);
scanf("%s", &f.type);
printf("\n");
structPrint();
}

structPrint()
{
printf("Filename: %s, File Size: %d, Type: [%s], Access Time: %d \n", &f.name, f.size,     &f.type, f.time);
}
```

Comment: You need to change the type of the `name` element in your struct from `char` to `char *` and allocate some memory for the string.  (You could also make it a `char` array.)

Comment: You aren't actually using `struct File *c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure contains space for exactly 1 character `type` and 1 character `name`.  Both of those are likely to be longer than a single character - in fact, they *must*, since they're presumably supposed to be null-terminated strings.  Try making those into arrays instead...

Comment: I switched it to char name [99] and it works! 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are storing name and type as `chars`, not `char[]`s. You can either allocate memory for them at runtime or declare them as arrays of fixed size. My code will use the latter.

Change the struct to something like this:

```
struct File {
    char type[12]; /*or whatever maximum sizes you think are appropriate */
    char name[64];
    int time;
    int size;
}f;
```

Remove the `&` operators in the `scanf` and `printf` calls for name and type.